# Minecraft how to testfor if a mob is looking at the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way I can testfor if a mob is looking at the player?  I know there is a way to testfor a certain rotation, but is there a way to test if the mob is looking in the general location of the player?

Comment: Would you mind if I took a look at this map when it's finished?

Comment: I actually haven't started on the map, I'm just testing out how I would go about doing things. But yeah when I finish the map you can have a look at it.

Comment: Have you tried using Sethbling's "Magic Nether Portal" concept? Only that you're also testing for mobs with a rotation +/- 180f? I'll give you a link and prototype when I get onto a computer..

Comment: Basically, it is the same system used, but instead of `/clone`ing the corresponding region to achieve an effect, it's to give every mob a dummy score that's about +/- 180f, while removing the scores who are not in that rotation range.

Comment: Why not use built-in mob tracking code? You could spawn in a zombie with a custom tracking range attribute, then use /testfor or /scoreboard players set @e {data} to test if it is tracking a player. You could also make this zombie invisible and have it be killed once it is detected, so the player never even knows it's there.

Comment: Is it possible you could get the position of both the mob and the player then use math to see if the rotation of the mob makes it facing towards the player?

Answer (score -1):

if using MC 1.8 you can summon an armorstand acording to the lets say Zombie's position and direction then test to see if the player is within the range (3 maybe?) of the armorstand

Answer (score -1):

there is no command combination/singular command that can't do that. yet.

Answer (score -3):

It could only be possible by making a plugin. You can test for the direction of the mob but not test a dynamic direction.